# How can I bin data to table or list in Sapui5

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I want to get data from user input and insert that data into a table or list. When the user clicks the insert button, the data will be inserted into the table. If the user clicks the delete button, the selected row will be deleted.

This my `home.view.xml`:

```xml
<Button text="insert" type="Unstyled" press="insContent"></Button>
<Button text="delete" type="Unstyled" press="deleteContent"></Button>
<l:Grid defaultSpan="L12 M12 S12" width="auto">
    <l:content>
        <f:SimpleForm columnsL="1" columnsM="1" editable="false" emptySpanL="4" emptySpanM="4" id="SimpleForm" labelSpanL="3" labelSpanM="3" layout="ResponsiveGridLayout" maxContainerCols="2" minWidth="1024">
            <f:content>
                <Label text="Name" id="lname"></Label>
                <Input value="" id="iname"></Input>
                <Label text="surname" id="lsurname"></Label>
                <Input value="" id="isurname"></Input>
            </f:content>
        </f:SimpleForm>
    </l:content>
</l:Grid>
<Table class="nwEpmRefappsShopControlLayout" growing="true" growingScrollToLoad="true" id="catalogTable">
    <columns>
        <Column demandPopin="true" id="descriptionColumn"></Column>
        <Column demandPopin="true" id="descriptionColumn2"></Column>
    </columns>
    <ColumnListItem class="nwEpmRefappsShopTableItemLayout" id="columnListItem" type="Active" vAlign="Middle">
        <cells>
            .
            .
        </cells>
    </ColumnListItem>
</Table>
```

This my `home.controller.js`:

```js
insContent: function () {
    // Get data from input 
    this.byId("iname").getValue();
    this.byId("isurname").getValue();
}
```

Comment: I think it would be a good idea to create a simple jsbin example that illustrates some code. Here is a template that you can use to create your jsbin. Fortunately, this template contains a table that is filled via odata. Are you using an ODataModel or JSONModel?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the link: https://www.nabisoft.com/tutorials/sapui5/sapui5-single-file-template-using-xmlviews-controllers-fragments-and-custom-controls-for-bug-illustrations-support-requests-or-demos

Comment: I am using json data. Your example getting data grom a service. I want a user input. Thx your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to make xml views but maybe this can help you.

First, you need to have a table with a model. For example (oTableData is a sap.m.Table object):

```
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
oModel.setData({modelData: aData});
oTableData.setModel(oModel);
oTableData.bindItems("/modelData", oRow);
```

Also you need an array for store data (in index.html).

```
var aData = [];
```

For add users you need the following function.

```
save: function(firstName, lastName) {
    // Add object to array
    aData.push({firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName});

    // Refresh model
    var oTableData = sap.ui.getCore().byId(this.createId("table"));
    oTableData.getModel().refresh();
}
```

Finally for delete users you have to add this to the table.

```
oTableData.setMode(sap.m.ListMode.Delete);
oTableData.attachDelete(function(oEvent) {
    var oSelectedItem = oEvent.getParameter("listItem");
    var sItemName = oSelectedItem.getBindingContext().getProperty("firstName");
    var path = oSelectedItem.getBindingContext().getPath();
    path = path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') +1);
    var model = oSelectedItem.getModel();
    var data = model.getProperty('/modelData');
    data.splice(parseInt(path), 1);
    model.setProperty('/modelData', data);

    sap.m.MessageToast.show("Deleted");
});
```

I make a repository for reference:

https://github.com/aosepulveda/sapui5-model-crud

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks your comment. Your answer is very helpfull . I changed my project diagram but I hope this answer will be a referance for other developers.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the first and last name using ids after clicking on the insert button. Once you have the values, create an object

```js
var object = {
    firstName: user_enteredValue,
    lasName: userEnteredSirName
};
```

Then, insert into your table model, i.e.

```js
table.getModel().getData().push(object);
table.getModel().refresh();
```

It will update your table with a new row.

Comment: oTable.getModel(...).getData(...).push is not a function

Comment: If the model has an array , it will work .. Due to method chaining , push is applied to the array .. Can you print your model structure..